# Plot of The RiemannSiegelZ Function

Tags: plotting, numerics, special-functions, code-review, precision-and-accuracy

I would appreciate your help to visualize the of the following function RiemannSiegelZ[x] with this range.

> **{ 18154980120849865 , 18154980120849885 }**

I tried this:

```
Plot[RiemannSiegelZ[x], 
{x, 18154980120849865,18154980120849865 + 20},
PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image]

Mathematica can't plot this function with very big number.

Another way:

```
  k = 0.5;
  ListLinePlot[
  Table[RiemannSiegelZ[18154980120849865 + n], {n, 0, 20, k}]]
```

by $k=0.5$ calculation takes a long time **(On my Laptop 555 seconds time to calculation )** , then you can somehow speed up.
I would like to have a Plot for $k = 0.01$ or less?

[image]

It should look more oscillatory?
[image]

something like this plot as above.
**Thank You.**

Comment: On my computer, the `Table` calculation in the question takes about two minutes.  And, as in the question, I obtain the wrong answer.  The problem is that `18154980120849865` us a 17-digit number, and the typical PC `$MachinePrecision` is about `15`.  This is the reason  for the steps in the `ListLinePlot`.  `RiemannSiegelZ[SetPrecision[18154980120849865.5, 20]]` gives better accuracy, but the calculation of this single point takes over ten minutes on my computer!  I am not optimistic that this can be improved upon using `RiemannSiegelZ`

Comment: [Tabulating values of the Riemann-Siegel Z function along the critical line](http://web.mit.edu/kenta/www/six/parallel/2-Final-Report.html) might be of help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the precision necessary to represent `18154980120849865.` slightly exceeds,

```
$MachinePrecision
(* 15.9546 *)
```

`RiemannSiegelZ` gives an inaccurate answer,

```
RiemannSiegelZ[18154980120849865.]
(* -0.563204 *)
```

as compared with

```
RiemannSiegelZ[SetPrecision[18154980120849865, 30]
(* 1.22954136 *)
```

and the same is true of the entire `ListLinePlot` shown in the Question.  A more accurate result is obtained from

```
{time, acc} = ParallelTable[RiemannSiegelZ[SetPrecision[18154980120849865, 30] 
    + SetPrecision[n, 30]], {n, 0, 20, .5}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {10313.5, {1.22954136, 0.45733188, 0.64249589, -0.23111788, -0.06772856, 1.86695945, 0.77054396, 29.75151621, -0.66752091, -1.27050184, 1.56098844, 6.83993776, 0.54517648, -0.36452725, -0.25932667, 4.81943341, -6.33776918, 0.68738205, 0.18835108, -0.25737550, 0.62239828, -0.31795652, 0.07475369, -1.41777198, 3.51921433, -11.93884182, -2.66443412, 4.74412021, 1.33297687, 2.63146428, 0.52462748, 0.42306865, -0.11443382, 0.39929218, -0.01647538, -0.35343551, 0.40905559, -0.22889455, -5.91871908, 0.77096701, -4.14144359}} *)
ListLinePlot[acc, DataRange -> {0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 2, Mesh -> Full, AxesLabel -> {x, RSZ}]
```

[image: plot of Riemann-Siegel function]

Note that obtaining this result required almost three hours on a 4-processor PC, compared to just over forty seconds to reproduce the result in the Question.  Although the resolution used to produce this figure clearly is too coarse, a twelve-hour calculation might be sufficient to produce useful results.

**Higher Resolution Plot**

A step size of `0.15` yields

```
{time, acc1} = ParallelTable[RiemannSiegelZ[SetPrecision[18154980120849865, 30] + 
    SetPrecision[n, 30]], {n, 0, 20, .15}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {31709.6, {1.22954136, 0.45498558, -3.85549214, 0.13830626, -0.28719155, -0.00090478, -0.31804223, 0.92669665, -1.70649749, 0.89596982, -0.23111788, -3.21092126, 3.12816513, -1.41706158, 9.02964508, 8.80864960, -0.85933757, 2.18532493, -2.61298054, 2.68883467, 0.77054396, 0.59337876, -7.36229693, 11.05578424, 57.39588680, 24.24769096, -7.39986612, 2.01751601, -0.58760314, 0.72837042, -1.27050184, -0.05804767, -0.30112026, 1.68059880, -2.82661794, -1.14182606, 11.72052461, 2.30906753, -1.48207013, 0.00355526, 0.54517648, 0.97624314, -0.75214925, 0.51317118, -1.92815687, 1.07123395, -0.60022863, 1.06528201, 0.15073717, -0.03807657, 4.81943341, -2.21733940, 1.04668274, -3.82362823, -3.45446930, 6.25291467, 0.11517578, 2.33205867, 1.20064902, -0.39354174, 0.18835108, -1.65870427, 0.06945072, -0.41259735, 0.18500629, -0.95850828, 0.45029760, 0.14051183, 0.37045442, -0.01229633, -0.31795652, 1.45396015, -1.09529959, 0.08312398, -0.20428558, 4.25814701, 1.29958856, -0.28066337, 1.94373684, -1.04288696, 3.51921433, -15.05489912, -4.13134149, 1.05541978, -35.51154243, -16.11413916, 0.32503284, -1.94806381, 1.25138353, -0.07076059, 4.74412021, -3.98814345, 5.37412445, 5.16634942, 0.30943278, 3.68171579, -5.40930838, 8.85803924, 9.01433622, -0.58710510, 0.52462748, -1.66083346, 0.64613365, -0.13747890, 2.31687408, -2.06521869, -3.13690034, 0.15667100, -0.91933125, 2.12524768, 0.39929218, 0.15446829, 0.05998516, 0.03387039, -1.13956458, -0.88283876, 0.82961360, -0.67314551, 0.11761984, -0.40280065, 0.40905559, -1.50031888, 0.72861288, -0.28840592, 6.99931604, 15.01597455, -5.89773363, 0.20046070, 7.73420552, -3.18166384, 0.77096701, -1.47647588, 2.02927971, -1.62931604}} *)
```

Then, merging this with the results for a step of `0.5` gives

```
Union[Table[{SetPrecision[.15 (i - 1), 30], acc[[i]]}, {i, Length[acc]}], 
      Table[{SetPrecision[.5 (i - 1), 30], acc1[[i]]}, {i, Length[acc1]}],
      SameTest -> (First[#1] == First[#2] &)];
ListLinePlot[%, PlotRange -> {All, {-14, 32}}, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 2, AxesLabel -> {x, RSZ}]
```

[image]

Because this plot does not change much to the eye, if only `acc1` is used, it seems likely that the qualitative features of the curve now have been captured.  Greater resolution would, of course, be needed for a quantitatively accurate curve.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's great help to me.

Answer (score 5):

Not an answer, but reporting a failed approach.

I looked for asymptotic expansions of the zeta function for large
arguments, thinking their evaluation might be faster. For instance, [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/RiemannSiegelZ/06/02/0003/)

The following took 100 s on my machine.

```
Plot[
   Re[(Exp[-((I (4 z^2 + Pi Sqrt[z^2]))/(8 z))] (z^2)^((I z)/4)
      Zeta[I z + 1/2])/(4^((I z)/4) Pi^((I z)/2))],
   {z, 10^12, 10^12 + 10}]
```

`ListPlot` is much faster because it can be evaluated at fewer points.
Values of z near 10^14 returned a slightly noisy plot in about 70 s.

```
ListPlot[
   ParallelTable[
      Re[(Exp[-((I (4 z^2 + Pi Sqrt[z^2]))/(8 z))] (z^2)^((I z)/4)
         Zeta[I z + 1/2])/(4^((I z)/4) Pi^((I z)/2))],
      {z, 10^14, 10^14 + 10, 0.02}], Joined -> True]
```

However, calculating just 20 values of z near 10^16 took about 300 s with 8 parallel kernels, and the blocky plot didn't really look correct...

```
ListPlot[
   ParallelTable[
      Re[(Exp[-((I (4 z^2 + Pi Sqrt[z^2]))/(8 z))] (z^2)^((I z)/4)
         Zeta[I z + 1/2])/(4^((I z)/4) Pi^((I z)/2))],
      {z, 10^16, 10^16 + 10, 0.5}], Joined -> True]
```

Perhaps these methods would help. [ref 1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1992.0053), [ref 2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1994.0121)

Comment: You had cited Paris's paper twice, so I removed the redundant link. :)